# How solve: Array type expected, found int? in bubble sort using array not the list

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

I have a task where I need to do a Bubble Sort program. I have to use array, not the list. I receive couple of errors, where it says that

> "Array type expected, found int"

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = {9, 7, 5, 8, 1, -5};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(array)));
    }

    public static int[] sort(int[] array) {
        int n = array.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {

                }
        return swapElementsInArray(array);
    }

    private static void swapElementsInArray(int[] array, int indexOfFirstElement, int indexOfSecondElement) {
        if (array[indexOfSecondElement] > array[indexOfSecondElement + 1]) {
            array [] = indexOfFirstElement[indexOfSecondElement];
            indexOfFirstElement[indexOfSecondElement] = indexOfFirstElement[indexOfSecondElement + 1];
            indexOfFirstElement[indexOfSecondElement + 1] = array;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to keep this structure, it's my tutor requirement to use these long names. And I cannot modify methods.

Comment: Not sure if that is the problem, but `array [] = indexOfFirstElement[indexOfSecondElement];` cannot work if `indexOfFirstElement` is an `int` and not an `int[]`, as one can see in the parameter definition of the method.

Comment: At what point do you get this error? Shoudn't you swap elements in that `if` in `sort` method? Also seems that `swapElementsInArray` has 3 parameters, but you call it with 1 argument

Comment: I added an answer @anabanana, didn't change method signatures or names. Just fixed the for/loop and the swap method that had wrong types, that's why the error you were getting in compilation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the method was wrong about what to swap and the error was wrong attribution - int into array.

Here is your example working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {9, 7, 5, 8, 1, -5};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(array)));
}

public static int[] sort(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                swapElementsInArray(array, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}

private static void swapElementsInArray(int[] array, int indexOfFirstElement, int indexOfSecondElement) {
    if (array[indexOfFirstElement] > array[indexOfSecondElement]) {
        int oldVal = array[indexOfFirstElement];
        array[indexOfFirstElement] = array[indexOfSecondElement];
        array[indexOfSecondElement] = oldVal;
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
[-5, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Improve points: your method swapElementsInArray() it was using wrong attribution. You first get the oldValue, adds the new position value and them move it to the second element. Another is the for/each where you don't need to read all values all the time. You can start j from i+1